# Forward Substitution Method

Tags: indexing

I have following matrix equation `[L][z]=[b]`
where `[L]` is `3x3` matrix and `z` (solution vector) and `b` (Right-hand side vector) are `3x1` vectors.

I want to find the solution vector(i.e., the values of `z0,z1,z2`)

The value for `z` I am getting is following
 z vector from Forward-substitution:

```
[ 106.8    177.2   -335.968]
```

link--https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uNBrCw0M3g

```
    import numpy as np
    L=np.array([[1.,   0.,   0.  ],
       [2.56, 1.,   0.  ],
       [5.76, 3.5,  1.  ]],float)
    print(L)
    # Right hand side vector
    b=np.array([106.8,177.2,279.2],float)
    n =len(b)
    z=np.zeros(n,float)   
    z[0]=b[0]/L[0,0]  ## or z[0]=b[0] because L[0,0]=1
    # print(z)
    #Forward Substitution method
    for i in range(1,n):
        sum_Lz=0
        for j in range(0,i-1):
            sum_Lz+=L[i,j]*z[j]
            # print(sum_Lz)
        z[i]=(b[i]-sum_Lz)/L[i,i]  ##L[i,i]=1
    print("z vector from forward substitution: ")
    print(z)
```

What basically I want to do is in each row (in each iteration I want to calculate enter code here z separately, z0,z1,z2)

For first iteration I have already separately defined `z[0]=b[0]/L[0,0]`. Then I run a for loop which start from second row `L[1,0]*z0 + L[1,1]*z1 = b[1]`, which gives value of `z1`, where I want to use `z0`, obtained from `b[0]/L[0,0]`. In third row similarly, `L[1,0]*z0 + L[1,1]*z1 = b[2]`, where, I want to use `z1` which I calculated in earlier iteration. This is how I get a solution vector z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**changing index from i-1 to i in j loop**

```
 import numpy as np
    L=np.array([[1.,   0.,   0.  ],
       [2.56, 1.,   0.  ],
       [5.76, 3.5,  1.  ]],float)
    print(L)

    # Right hand side vector
    b=np.array([106.8,177.2,279.2],float)
    n =len(b)
    z=np.zeros(n,float)   
    z[0]=b[0]/L[0,0]  ## or z[0]=b[0] because L[0,0]=1
    # print(z)
    #Forward Substitution method
    for i in range(1,n):
        sum_Lz=0
        for j in range(0,i):
            sum_Lz+=L[i,j]*z[j]
            # print(sum_Lz)
        z[i]=(b[i]-sum_Lz)/L[i,i]  ##L[i,i]=1
    print("z vector from forward substitution: ")
    print(z)
```